# Best way to do this loop in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put add a different layout for the first post. This is 100% width, and below the rest of the post 50% (two columns).

I am using Bootstrap, this is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">

<article></article>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-6">
<article></article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<article></article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<article></article>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<article></article>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

I know two ways to achieve this: Make two loops. In the first call the first post, and in the second loop call the rest. Or make only one loop, and use a counter like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199556/how-do-i-display-wordpress-posts-into-3-columns-horizontally).

But what will be a best practice? Is there a reason for doing one or another?

Comment: Use the second solution (Counter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more loops you make, more is your complexity. Loop inside loop makes your code less optimized. Use counter, it does not count in the complexity. It is just a variable. Secondly yes for every condition check e.g `if` statement it has to do some work but if you use loop as you know there are multiple condition checks in loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code

```
<?php 
    if( have_posts() ) :
        $counter = 0;
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        $counter++;
?>
        <?php if( $counter == 1) { ?>
            <div class="col-sm-9">

                <article></article>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if( $counter ==2 )  { ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <article></article>
                    </div>
            <?php }  else { ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <article></article>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

you can also do it with rewind_posts() though , if you want a cleaner code
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts